# Why wasn't a Clone method put in System.Object?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, data-structures

So I'm reading my C# book and it has an example of how to create a method for creating a deep copy of an object:

```
[Serializable]
public class DeepClone : IDeepCopy<DeepClone>
{
    public int data = 1;
    public List<string> ListData = new List<string>();
    public object objData = new Object();
    public DeepClone DeepCopy ()
    {
        BinaryFormatter BF = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream memSfream = new MemoryStream();
        BF.Serialize(memStream,this);
        memStream.Flush();
        memStream.Position = 0;
        return (DeepClone)BF.Deserialize(memStream);
    }
}
```

But the method `DeepCopy` is general enough that it doesn't depend on the other members

```
    public int data = 1;
    public List<string> ListData = new List<string>();
    public object objData = new Object();
```

of the object. As far as I can tell, this method could be put in any `class` and would work just the same. Additionally, how to copy an object is a question that many C# programmers have when they first use the language, as evidenced by the popularity of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects).

This brings up the question I have about why `System.Object` wasn't given a clone function. I bet programmers more often need a `Clone` method than a `GetHashcode` method, after all.

Comment: "I bet programmers more often need a Clone method than a GetHashcode method" I don't think I've used `Clone` more than I've used `GetHashCode`, and there's debate about whether `GetHashCode` should have been in `Object`. Not everything is suitable to be cloned and not everything is suitable to be used as keys in hashtables.

Comment: The .NET designers learned that lesson pretty well from C++.  A language that very often creates programs that misbehave badly because the programmer did not implement cloning correctly.  There is nothing pretty about it, ICloneable narrowly escaped getting deprecated.  It is much less necessary in .NET thanks to garbage collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all classes can support cloning. Singleton objects by their very definition cannot be cloned. OO dictates that such classes should not contain a `Clone` method. Since classes cannot avoid inheriting `System.Object`, the method should not be introduced at that level. (The same reasoning should apply to methods `ToString()`, `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`, but I guess someone decided otherwise.)

In addition to the interface aspect, cloning is not as trivial as it seems, e.g. when child objects store references to their parents. For example, when cloning a (WinForms or other) control, you'd probably want child controls cloned as well, but not the parent control. Now which references need cloning and which don't? This makes it difficult (if not impossible) to implement cloning correctly for all cases.

Comment: Why not give every object a clone method and leave it up to the developer to decide whether or not it makes sense to use it on a particular object?

Comment: Hillary: my edited answer addresses this. You don't want a fat interface with methods that make no sense at the derived level. Derived classes will have no option but to throw, making the interface meaningless.